# How do I order the x-axis by date in R using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm learning data visualization using R and as a personal project I decided to track and plot all of my workouts. My csv file has three columns: "Date", "Activity", and "Duration". I'm having trouble getting the dates to appear in the right order on the graph.

Here is my code:

```
log <- read_csv("Training Log.csv")

ggplot(log, aes(Date,Duration))+
  geom_col(aes(fill=Activity))+
  ylab("Duration (min)")
```

Details about my tibble using `dput(log)`:

```
structure(list(Date = c("2/6", "2/9", "2/11", "2/13", "2/15", 
"2/16", "2/17", "2/18", "2/19", "2/19", "2/21", "2/24", "2/25", 
"2/26", "2/27", "2/28", "3/1", "3/2", "3/3", "3/3"), Activity = c("BJJ (Gi)", 
"BJJ (Nogi)", "Lifting", "BJJ (Gi)", "BJJ (Gi)", "Lifting", "Lifting", 
"BJJ (Gi)", "Tennis", "Lifting", "BJJ (Gi)", "BJJ (Gi)", "BJJ (Gi)", 
"Lifting", "BJJ (Gi)", "BJJ (Gi)", "BJJ (Gi)", "BJJ (Nogi)", 
"BJJ (Gi)", "Lifting"), Duration = c(90, 90, 40, 60, 60, 40, 
40, 120, 30, 30, 75, 90, 90, 45, 140, 70, 120, 60, 60, 30)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The result looks like the plot below, where it mostly goes in chronological order but puts dates like 2/6 and 2/9 after the rest of February's. I am hoping to make the x-axis fully chronological.

A bonus feature would be showing dates I didn't exercise with values of 0 for duration, but that might be too complicated for right now.

[image: plot with non-chronological dates]

Comment: Check your variable types. It seems that your date is a `Factor`. BTW you can use `dput(your data.frame)` (such as `dput(log)` in your case) to output you data into code. Then, you can post it as part of your R code.

Comment: @Ryan I ran `typeof(log$Date)` and it returned "character" so I'm a bit confused about that part. But thank you for informing me about the `dput` function!

Comment: the `character` also does not work. you need transfer it to `date` or other datetime types such as `POSIXct`.

Comment: @Ryan Ok, that makes sense, I converted it and it is in the right order now! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
log = structure(list(Date = c("2/6", "2/9", "2/11", "2/13", "2/15", 
                        "2/16", "2/17", "2/18", "2/19", "2/19", "2/21", "2/24", "2/25", 
                        "2/26", "2/27", "2/28", "3/1", "3/2", "3/3", "3/3"), Activity = c("BJJ (Gi)", 
                                                                                          "BJJ (Nogi)", "Lifting", "BJJ (Gi)", "BJJ (Gi)", "Lifting", "Lifting", 
                                                                                          "BJJ (Gi)", "Tennis", "Lifting", "BJJ (Gi)", "BJJ (Gi)", "BJJ (Gi)", 
                                                                                          "Lifting", "BJJ (Gi)", "BJJ (Gi)", "BJJ (Gi)", "BJJ (Nogi)", 
                                                                                          "BJJ (Gi)", "Lifting"), Duration = c(90, 90, 40, 60, 60, 40, 
                                                                                                                               40, 120, 30, 30, 75, 90, 90, 45, 140, 70, 120, 60, 60, 30)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                          -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
log$Date = as.Date(paste("2023/",log$Date,sep = ""))
ggplot(log, aes(Date,Duration))+
  geom_col(aes(fill=Activity))+
  ylab("Duration (min)")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here is on wy how we could do it:

First we separate Date into Month and Day and then we create a date adding year 2023 to day and month. Now we can use complete to add the days that are not in the date column. Finally we use fct_inorder:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  separate(Date, into = c("Month", "Day"), remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(mydate = dmy(paste(Day, Month, "2023", sep="-"))) %>% 
  mutate(max_day = ceiling_date(mydate, "month")- days(1)) %>% 
  complete(mydate = seq(min(dmy(paste("1",Month,"2023"))), max(max_day), by = "day")) %>% 
  mutate(Month = month(mydate),
         Day = day(mydate)) %>% 
  mutate(Date = format(mydate, "%m/%d")) %>% 
  arrange(Month, Day) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=fct_inorder(Date),Duration, fill=Activity))+
  geom_col()+
  ylab("Duration (min)")
```

[image]